# Data conflict with inheritance in Javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to work on a lib in JavaScript, and I have an inheritance problem. Here is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Fruit = function () {
    this.colors = [];
}

Lemon = function () {
    this.colors.push("yellow");
}

Lemon.prototype = new Fruit();
```

Here, I wanted to create a class *Lemon*, inheriting from a class *Fruit*, with each fruit containing a list of colors.

But when I try to instantiate some lemons and print their colors like this:

```
var lemon1 = new Lemon();
console.log(lemon1.colors);
var lemon2 = new Lemon();
console.log(lemon1.colors);
console.log(lemon2.colors);
```

I get this output:

```
["yellow"]
["yellow", "yellow"]
["yellow", "yellow"]
```

So I can see the problem is the attribute "colors" is one array shared between each instance of Lemon object.

How to make a different colors array for each lemon instance, with a definition in the Fruit class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
Fruit = function () {
    this.colors = [];
}

Lemon = function () {
    Fruit.call(this);
    this.colors.push("yellow");
}

Lemon.prototype = Object.create(Fruit);
```

Call the `Fruit` constructor from the `Lemon` constructor: `Fruit.call(this);`. Also rather than invoking the constructor to create the prototype, we use `Object.create(Fruit)` which create the object without calling its constructor.

Running your examples gives the following with the above definitions.

```
> var lemon1 = new Lemon();
> console.log(lemon1.colors);
[ 'yellow' ]
> var lemon2 = new Lemon();
> console.log(lemon1.colors);
[ 'yellow' ]
> console.log(lemon2.colors);
[ 'yellow' ]
```

To that I add:

```
> Object.is(lemon1.colors, lemon2.colors)
false
```

Which shows that the `Lemon` instances have distinct `Array`s for the value of their `colors` property.